# get results from kafka for a specific period of time

Tags: python, apache-kafka, consumer, kafka-python

Here is my code, that uses `kafka-python`.

```
now = datetime.now()
month_ago = now - relativedelta(month=1)
topic = 'some_topic_name'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=PROD_KAFKA_SERVER,
                         security_protocol=PROTOCOL,
                         group_id=GROUP_ID,
                         enable_auto_commit=False,
                         sasl_mechanism=SASL_MECHANISM, sasl_plain_username=SASL_USERNAME,
                         sasl_plain_password=SASL_PASSWORD)


for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)
```

I want to get results from topic just between `now` and `month_ago` in a loop. How can I do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I do this :) My code looks like this:

```
topic = 'some_topic_name'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=PROD_KAFKA_SERVER,
                         security_protocol=PROTOCOL,
                         group_id=GROUP_ID,
                         sasl_mechanism=SASL_MECHANISM, sasl_plain_username=SASL_USERNAME,
                         sasl_plain_password=SASL_PASSWORD)

month_ago = (datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)).timestamp()
topic_partition = TopicPartition(topic, 0)
assigned_topic = [topic_partition]
consumer.assign(assigned_topic)

partitions = consumer.assignment()
partition_to_timestamp = {part: int(month_ago * 1000) for part in partitions}
end_offsets = consumer.end_offsets(list(partition_to_timestamp.keys()))

mapping = consumer.offsets_for_times(partition_to_timestamp)
for partition, ts in mapping.items():
    end_offset = end_offsets.get(partition)
    consumer.seek(partition, ts[0])
    for msg in consumer:
        value = json.loads(msg.value.decode('utf-8'))
        # do something
        if msg.offset == end_offset - 1:
            consumer.close()
            break
```

Answer (score 5):

Get topic partitions, assigned to your consumer:

```py
partitions = consumer.assignment()
```

Get offsets for partitions by datetime:

```py
month_ago_timestamp = int(month_ago.timestamp() * 1000)
partition_to_timestamp = {part: month_ago_timestamp for part in partitions}
mapping = consumer.offsets_for_times(partition_to_timestamp)
```

Seek partitions to offsets:

```
for partition, offset_and_timestamp in partition_to_offset_and_timestamp.items():
    consumer.seek(partition, offset_and_timestamp[0])
```

Warning! Consumer can return None, set with int zero or block indefinitely in cases like missing topic, missing partition or messages without timestamp

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot :)