# create alerts for the incoming data in azure eventhubs or azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-alerts

I would like to create an alert if specific data is not received  to the eventhubs (or azure functions) in the past 6 hours(eg: I will be receiving student information to my eventhubs everyday and today If I don't receive information about studentId=1 then send an alert about that). I was able to create alerts for exceptions, total counts but not sure how to query the incoming data and I do have message retention set to 7 days.

Comment: See if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409971/get-results-from-kafka-for-a-specific-period-of-time
The high level idea would be to consume message for that day and check the message has your key and send a notification.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, currently there is no feature to read the specific incoming messages in an **Azure Alert**.

Azure Alert can read the metrics only we cannot compare or read a specific incoming/outgoing message.

If you want to Read/ Compare the incoming messages from eventhub either you have to use the ***Python script/Azure Function/Logic App*** to **Validate/Compare** whether the ***studentID*** is present in a incoming messages or not.

#### Reference

- [Logic app store the values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values)